# c# list index 0 showing value as -1

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I am creating a basic program in unity where I check a list array index carry out a certain action depending on the value, I then increment the index.The problem I am having is that the array always stores in index 0 and always equals -1.

```
    public class numGen(){  
    int val;
    int i = 0;

    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        val = rnd.Next(1, 5);
        arrayList.Add(val);

        Debug.Log("val"+val);
        Debug.Log("array"+arrayList.IndexOf(i));

        if (arrayList.IndexOf(i) == 1)
         {
                Debug.Log("action1");
                i++;
         }
        else if (arrayList.IndexOf(i) == 2)
                {
                  Debug.Log("action2");
                  i++;
                }
           //and so on
    }
```

I have used debug in the log, so val will output a expected value, e.g. 2, gets added into the array when I check the value stored in the index it's -1.

Not sure how or why the int value is changing.

Comment: What is the variable `i` ?

Comment: int i = 0; to start with

Comment: correct for index zero, that's where arrays always start.  Why expect anything else?

Comment: If `.IndexOf()` returns -1 it means whatever you are passing to it is not in the collection

Comment: I under stand how the index works, but if I put in two values, 1 then 2. index 0 should = 1 and index 1 should = 2. but index 0 will = 1 then get over written and equal 2. Please not i is declared its in my class definition

Comment: Can yoy post the complete for loop with initialization of arraylist too? Some explanation about the logic would also be helpful.

Comment: "Please not i is declared its in my class definition " You should show the class definition and the declaration of I. (Note, you can leave out other methods that do not pertain to this question.)

Comment: 1. Please fix the indentation. Every line of code should have 4 extra spaces before the spaces you need to actually indent in order to allow SO to format it properly. 2. The code you have given is not correct C# since there is no method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is a misunderstanding how `ArrayList` and `IndexOf()` works.

### [ArrayList.IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d751f6sy(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Searches for the specified Object** and **returns the zero-based index** of the first occurrence within the range of elements in the ArrayList that starts at the specified index and contains the specified number of elements.

So your exception comes from:

> The zero-based index of the first occurrence of value within the range of elements in the ArrayList that starts at startIndex and contains count number of elements, if found; otherwise, -1.

---

I think your are looking for something like this:

### [ArrayList.Item()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.item(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the element at the specified index.

Also it's possible to

> This property provides the ability **to access a specific element in the collection by using the following syntax: myCollection[index]**.

An example in your case:

```
if (arrayList[i] == 1)
{
   // if true..
}
```

Comment: This is correct - `IndexOf(...)` returns the index in the array for the given value - so, `['a', 'b', 'c'].IndexOf('b')` would return `1`, while `.IndexOf('z')` returns `-1`, indicating that the value is not found in the array.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for fixing the Copy-Paste-Error ;)

Comment: @Phil3992 You should post a new question showing that different error and the exact code which causes it.

Comment: @Phil3992 No, do not use `IndexOf()` ! And in no case `IndexOf[]` !!! This is wrong.

Comment: @Phil3992 Also be sure to refresh this page. The original answer had an error in the final code snippet. The error has been fixed and the current version of the code is correct.

Comment: My page hadn't refreshed. I am now using the correct syntax

Answer (score 2):

`arrayList.IndexOf(i)` gives the index of any element with the **value** of `i`. If you want the value at **index** `i`, you must use `arrayList[I]` instead.

Comment: To get element at index one can use `arrayList[i]` (and casting).

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks. I was in the middle of editing just as you commented.

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf gives the index of the value you give. If there is no equal value found in the array it returns -1

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
arr.Add(5);
arr.Add(2);
var isMinusOne = arr.IndexOf(0); //Is -1
var isZero = arr.IndexOf(5); //Is 0
```